# Technet and trying to install Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, installation

I'm a Technet subscriber and a bit new to it all so I'm just trying to work my way round things.

Firstly I want to install Windows Server 2008 R2 as I believe this is the latest edition - however when I look to download it from Technet, it will only allow me to download the Windows Automated Installation Kit.  Does this have Windows Server 2008 R2 embedded in WAIK  or is there some other extra step to do?  Or am I just doing this all wrong :)

Comment: are you downloading via technet account or are you looking for the docs on technet and downloading the trial

Comment: @Jim B - I hold a technet account and I'm trying to download the actual Windows 2008 R2 software, not this WAIK software which seems to be the only thing on offer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just select "All platforms" instead of "32bit" in the top selector next to the language. 2008 R2 is the first 64bit-only OS from MS.

Comment: Yep - It's only for 64 bit systems, I see.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a subscriber server 2008r2 is under subscriber downloads.  For nonsubscribers the eval version is available [here](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/trial-software.aspx).  The only difference between the 2 is that 1 expires and the technet version doesn't.  Also as a subscriber you get concierge support should you have trouble locating a download/article/resource.

Comment: The only thing under the subscriber downloads I see under "Windows Server 2008 R2" is the WAIK software and nothing else, is this right?

Answer (score 0):

WAIK is a separate tool (to assist in rapid deployment).  If it's not showing up in the list, and SvenW's suggestion doesn't help - you would see something called Windows Server 2008 R2 - then you may need to contact Microsoft to find out if there's a problem with what downloads are associated with your account.